# solr unable to search with exact value

Tags: apache, configuration, solr, lucene, indexing

I am using Solr 4.1.0 and I'm facing a strange issue. If I give a value to search for a field, even be it exact or involving a wildcard, it gives me 0 search results. On the other hand if I just give the field name and a * in place of value, I get all the results.

Also, if I search in the text field, i.e where I have copied values of all my fields, it gives me correct output. text is by default, my catch-all for all fields. feature is a field which has value Butter.

So now, what is happening here is that if I try to find in the actual field with the exact value or even with starting alphabet and a *, it doesn't give me a value while if I search in the text field, which is a catch-all field, I'm able to retrieve the value. Although if I try to find in the feature field using *, it gives me complete result list correctly.

You can view the logs for `text:Butter` [here](http://pastebin.com/LK8bqjSJ), logs for `feature:Butter` [here](http://pastebin.com/nqmhvfJw), logs for `feature:B*` [here](http://pastebin.com/XaExUWqN) and logs for `feature:*` [here](http://pastebin.com/rQrp3C1y)

I'm facing this issue with this particular field only. Any pointers to what could be the reason behind this strange problem?

Comment: Can you please add the field definition and the corresponding fieldType for your feature field from the schema.xml file.

Comment: Hi @paige! Thanks for trying to help me out here. The given field is dynamic in my case and this is the field definition: type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"

Answer (score 0):

If you search without the field name, Solr is going to search in the default search field.
So make sure you are marking the fields you want to search on as default.
If you are using dismax query handler, you can add them to the qf parameter.

Also, for Wildcard Queries check [Analyzers][1]

```
On wildcard and fuzzy searches, no text analysis is performed on the search word.
```

As no analysis is done at query time for wilcard searches and hence the lower casing, stemming would not be applied during query time but just the index time.

Comment: Hi @Jayendra! But I'm using a field name, see feature is the name of the field.

Comment: Cant see the logs. text:Butter does not return any results ?? and butter is indexed in the text field ?? whats the field type text_general definition ?? can you post in your question ?

Comment: whats the field type for feature field ? can you post your schema.xml ?

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be able to copy the complete schema file but it is the default solr schema.xml with just a few field additions. This is the field definition for feature field which is a dynamic field: type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"

Comment: how are the dynamic fields mapped ??? does the feature field have any data ?? or some copyfield directives overriding the others ? Without looking into schema we wont be of much help.

Comment: yes @Jayendra, we have data in that field. If you look at logs, you can see this. feature is a dynamic field which has values and later it is copied to a field text using `<copyField source="feature" dest="text"/>` and this is my field definition for catchall text field `<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>`

Comment: what else would you like to know or see @Jayendra ?

Comment: what is the definition of the dynamic field ?

Comment: <dynamicField name="*ture" type="text_general" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" />

Comment: what else do we need here ?

Comment: So, how did you solve it ?! I'm facing the same problem